# Scripts are like a box of sweets

Tags: knowledge, movies

Scripts are like a box of sweets, you never know if a line or two is going to stick in people's mind.  Just imagine if the scriptwriters asked the actors to say:

1

> It's breathing! It's breathing!

2

> Plainly speaking, I do not care one way or another.

3

> You cannot comprehend the facts.

4

> I will search for you, I will locate you and I will dispose of you.

5

> I shall revisit.

6

> Top of the day, you communist country.

7

> Alien calling base.

8

> Do not misjudge the influence of evil.

9

> Spy, top spy.

10

> You spitting words at me?

11

> May the imaginary field surround you.

12

> If you construct it, he will visit.

13

> I am traversing the road here!

14

> I notice corpses.

15

> Ground control, we have a complication.

16

> Au Revoir, darling.

17

> Say your greetings to this little thing.

18

> My treasure.

19

> Use another way to make my alcoholic drink.

20

> I am going to make him a proposition that he thinks it's really really good.

21

> I am on top of the world!

22

> I will order the same dish as her.

I would be surprised if this puzzle takes more than 10 minutes to solve.

*Bonus:* Just for fun, can you identify the actors who said them without Googling?

Comment: Nice one. But, actually, you didn't *ask* anything (other than the bonus) :c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nobody yet? Okay I'll throw up the partial answer, then!

In the spirit of the bonus, I have not looked up any of the actors. I'm surprised how many of these I knew off the top of my head!

1. It's breathing! It's breathing!

   > IT'S ALIVE! IT'S ALIIIIIIIIIIIIVE! - Colin Clive, Frankenstein
2. Plainly speaking, I do not care one way or another.

   > Frankly, my dear, I don't give a damn. - Clark Gable, Gone With The Wind
3. You cannot comprehend the facts.

   > YOU CAN'T HANDLE THE TRUTH! - Jack Nicholson, A Few Good Men
4. I will search for you, I will locate you and I will dispose of you.

   > I will hunt you down, I will find you, and I will kill you. - Liam Neeson, Taken
5. I shall revisit.

   > I'll be back. - Arnold Schwarzenegger, Terminator (does it count if I had to google his name to remember how to spell it?)
6. Top of the day, you communist country.

   > Good Morning, Vietnam! - Robin Williams, Good Morning Vietnam (thanks to JoeZ)
7. Alien calling base.

   > E.T. phone home. - ???, ET The Extraterrestrial (thanks to Bailey M)
8. Do not misjudge the influence of evil.

   > Do not underestimate the power of the Dark Side. - James Earl Jones, Star Wars
9. Spy, top spy.

   > Bond. James Bond. -Sean Connery (and many other), [basically every James Bond movie]
10. You spitting words at me?

    > You talkin' to me? - Robert DeNiro, Taxi Driver
11. May the imaginary field surround you.

    > May the Force be with you. - A number of people, but I'll go with Harrison Ford, Star Wars
12. If you construct it, he will visit.

    > If you build it, he will come. -Kevin Costner, Field of Dreams
13. I am traversing the road here!

    > Hey, I'm walkin' here, I'm walkin' here! - Dustin Hoffman, Midnight Cowboy
14. I notice corpses.

    > I see dead people. - Haley Joel Osment, The Sixth Sense
15. Ground control, we have a complication.

    > Houston, we have a problem. - Tom Hanks, Apollo 13
16. Au Revoir, darling.

    > 'Hasta la vista, baby' – Arnold Schwarzenegger, Terminator 2 (answered by Tim Couwelier in comments below)
17. Say your greetings to this little thing.

    > Say hello to my little friend. - Al Pacino, Scarface
18. My treasure.

    > My preciousssssss. - Andy Serkis, Lord of the Rings (Thanks Bailey M)
19. Use another way to make my alcoholic drink.

    > Shaken, not stirred. - [insert James Bond actor], [insert James Bond movie]
20. I am going to make him a proposition that he thinks it's really really good.

    > I'll make him an offer he can't refuse. - Marlon Brando, The Godfather
21. I am on top of the world!

    > I'm king of the world! - Leonardo DiCaprio, Titanic
22. I will order the same dish as her.

    > I'll have what she's having. - Estelle Reiner, When Harry Met Sally (actor answered by dmg in comment below)

I am positive I'm missing some obvious ones.

Comment: 7 is "E.T. phone home."

Comment: And 18 is "My preciousssss.."

Comment: Hmm, you got more than I did in that time... I somehow knew most of those quotes, but only started answering about 10 minutes ago :P

Comment: And 6 is "Good Morning Vietnam".

Comment: @JoeZ. Yeah, when I first saw it, I didn't even bother with trying to put together an answer because I figured someone would beat me to it. After it had been up for almost an hour, though, I decided to take a crack at it.

Comment: I don't know any of the actors (without Googling) for the answers in the comments, so if you know 'em, let me know!

Comment: "Good Morning, Vietnam" was Robin Williams.

Comment: And I'm fairly sure Meg Ryan was the "she" in 22, not the speaker.

Comment: Number 16 is wrong. Whoever said it wasn't talking in English.

Comment: #4 is "I will **look for you**, I will find you and I will kill you."

Comment: @Eli Is it "Sayonara, bitches"?

Comment: 16 could be Adios Amigos

Comment: Hey, I added the actors names except ET.

Comment: @Joez, lol. I like it, but no. I really thought 16 would be the easiest one to get, given that it's another classic quote from the same actor in the same franchise.

Comment: I don't expect anyone to get the actor for 22. The answer is correct, but the person who said it is not a known actor.

Comment: @Eli It was the director's mother, although I can't recall either of their names. She says it because of what Meg did.

Comment: 16 - 'Hasta la vista, baby'

Comment: ^ I should have known.

Comment: Darnit, this one was right up my alley. Oh well :P   Nice one Eli

Comment: @TimCouwelier, and 'Hasta la vista, baby' is correct.

Comment: Just roaming through highest voted 'movies' questions around... 19 was said by Daniel Craig in _Casino Royale_.